# How to click a nested link in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click a link on my website with Selenium but I cannot find any way to succeed.

My link ( Mitarbeiterverwaltung is what I want to click ) is within a nested HTML and when you hover with your mouse then the links will be dropped down.

I am able to get the link text but I am not able to click the link.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="dropdownAdmin">
    <button class="dropbtnAdmin" th:text="#{konto}">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-admin">
        <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
            <a href="/mitarbeiterverwaltung">Mitarbeiterverwaltung</a>
            <a href="/registration" th:text="#{benutzerregistrierung}"></a>
                        </div>
            <a href="/passwordaenderung" th:text="#{passwort_aendern}"></a>
                <div>
                  <a href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" > Sign out </a>
                  <form name="logoutForm" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" th:hidden="true">
                      <input hidden type="submit" value="Logout"/>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my last try in Java

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdownAdmin']//div[@class='dropdown-content-admin']").linkText("Mitarbeiterverwaltung")).click();
```

This was another try in order to prove that I am able to see the link text:

```
List<WebElement> link_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdownAdmin']//div[@class='dropdown-content-admin']//a").name("mitarbeiterverwaltung"));
for (int i=0;i<link_list.size();i++) {
    WebElement element = link_list.get(i);
    String contents = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println("Values from dropdown is : "+contents);
}
```

Maybe someone can give me a good hint how to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is mean by nested HTML here? And what do you mean by link will be dropped down? Try with this locator `//a[contains(@href, 'registration')]` or try to use the JavaScriptExecutor

Comment: What I mean is that I have my links within two nested <div> and it is a drop down list. This list will be opened as soon as I hover over with my mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your statement you need to hover drop-down and then you need to click on particular text.I have tried a bit but since I don't have application under test, please try the below code let me know if this work.

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-content-admin']"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();        
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung')]")).getText());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung')]")).click();
```

Comment: Not quite working: I get the following exception: ElementNotVisibleException.

Comment: Which steps are you getting the error.Before hover or after hover.Can you please put delay after hover to see any difference.

Comment: I really cannot answer the question regarding when does the error happens because it runs through the code and after tearing down the connection I get the Exception. I put a wait after action.moveToElement => driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but I got the same error message.

Comment: I can see your answer.you have just copy paste concept of my answer and telling that it’s not quite working.sometimes you should appreciate OP effort rather complaining.we can’t access you application what we could do here to guide you to resolve the problem.

Comment: I am sorry that was not my attention. I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem now.

I had to go through all s and then do a click.

Maybe there is a shorter version but I am sorry I do not know and for the moment this is working.

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownAdmin']"));
builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
WebElement elementa=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-content-admin']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung')]")).click();

String title = driver.getTitle();
assertTrue(title.contains("Mitarbeiterverwaltung"));
```